Creating a schedule expression for eventbridge using terraform
I am creating resources on AWS using TF and running into an error while trying to create an event bridge scheduler.
Based on TF documentation itself,
schedule_expression = "rate(1 hours)"
Since, I want the event bridge to fire at 8:30am every morning on weekdays and also 5:30pm on weekdays, I used the expression below
schedule_expression = "rate(30 8,17 ? * 2-6 *)"
My pipeline constantly returns this error saying expression is invalid
creating AWS EventBridge Scheduler Schedule (auto-stop-ec2): operation error Scheduler: CreateSchedule, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: baea3d64-f093-4394-a598-509f959c7010, ValidationException: Invalid Schedule Expression rate(30 8,17 ? * 2-6 *).
can any one please offer any advice on what I am doing wrong?

According to Schedule types on EventBridge Scheduler, the syntax to use a Cron-based schedule is the following:
cron(minutes hours day-of-month month day-of-week year)


I want the event bridge to fire at 8:30am every morning on weekdays and also 5:30pm on weekdays

Try the following:
schedule_expression = "cron(30 8,17 ? * MON-FRI *)"

You can validate the above expression using CronHub.

MON-FRI and 2-6 are synonymous in EventBridge scheduler, so this replacement wasn't necessary. The problem is only cron vs rate: cron is, durprisingly, for a cron-like definition, while rate is a less powerful interval-based solution (like rate(5 minutes))

MON-FRI and 2-6 are synonymous in EventBridge scheduler, so this replacement wasn't necessary - I've replaced for 2 reasons: 1) it's clearer to use MON-FRI and 2) when testing the 2-6 expression in CronHub it shows me Tuesday through Saturday.

@RuiJarimba The above expression actually worked. I find it interesting because the TF docs said to use rate. Was surprised cron actually worked here. Thank you so much.
